# Error in Social-share-button gem with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I've been trying to make use of social-share-button gem. See the link below. https://github.com/huacnlee/social-share-button

But the problem is i do not understand what

```
<%= social_share_button_tag(@post.title) %>
```

mean from the link. 
I'm using the controller 'Entry,' so I did

```
<%= social_share_button_tag(@Entry.title) %>
```

but it did not work. so I just did

```
<%= social_share_button_tag("") %>
```

and it did work except that when I click the buttons shown, it does not goes to "share link."

Hope I can get some understanding from this! Thanks!

Comment: The second syntax you have written seems correct. How did you initialize the @Entry variable?

Comment: is @Entry supposed to be @entry? Do you get any errors in the Javascript or Rails console when you click the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of using gem is follow:

```
social_share_button_tag("text to share")
```

Or if Facebook share button needed:

```
social_share_button_tag("text to share", url: 'https://www.yourdomain.com', desc: 'description for facebook')
```

In your case you need to replace "text to share" with actual variable in your code, which can be *@post.title* or *@ntry.title* and make same for *url:* and *desc:*

So it will look like

```
social_share_button_tag(@entry.title, url: @entry.url, desc: @entry.description)
```

Hope it helps!